# Shipping discount based on user roles in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, discount

I tried to implement a code snippet for functions.php that will apply
   a 50% discount to the delivery charge when the "admin" role and want
   to hide it goes in free delivery mode.

It does not work as I would like. What I am doing wrong?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','discount_based_on_user_role_and_payment', 20, 1 );
function discount_based_on_user_role_and_payment( $cart) {
if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
    return;
    $discount = WC()->cart->shipping_total/2;
if ( $discount >0 && !current_user_can('administrator') )
    return;
    $cart->add_fee( sprintf( __("Chiết khấu", "woocommerce")), -$discount, true );
}
```

Could anyone help complete this? Or atleast point to the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `return;` before the adding the fee, nothing happen.
Instead use this lightly changed code version:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','discount_based_on_user_role_and_payment', 20, 1 );
function discount_based_on_user_role_and_payment( $cart) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return; 

    $discount = $cart->shipping_total / 2;

    if ( $discount > 0 && current_user_can('administrator') ) {
        $cart->add_fee( sprintf( __("Chiết khấu", "woocommerce")), -$discount, true );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). tested and works.